# How to paste element after the second array's element

Tags: php

I have a mysql query which request the news on my website I use the

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($count) {
    while ($myarray = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $myarray['headline'];
    $myarray['content'];
    }
}
```

What have i done if i would like to paste like a video after the first news? So between the first and the second one i would love to paste one youtube video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to insert an array element to a specific position, in your case we have to do as follows.

```
$result = array_slice($myarray, 0, 1, true) +
    array("youtube" => "youtube.com") +
    array_slice($myarray, 1, count($myarray) - 1, true) ;
print_r($result);
```

it will print;

```
Array
(
    [headline] => your headline
    [youtube] => youtube.com
    [content] => your content
)
```